# (CHIP8 Emulator) Why is memory taken as char datatype

Tags: c, emulation, chip-8

new to emudev starting out by building a CHIP8 emulator in C. why is its [4k memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8#Virtual_machine_description) takes as `char` datatype? I believe I am missing some really fundamental information. help

also, what are flags? CHIP8 has 16 (15?) registers VN from 0-F to carry flags. What does it mean?

Thanks :)

Comment: *why is its 4k memory takes as char datatype? * - what does it mean? Why the memory is represented as `char` array in some *specific implementation* ? Probably because `char` is an 8-bit data type on most implementations, and is corresponding to a conventional "byte"...

Comment: `char` could be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation, so `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` would be preferable for representing the value of a byte.

Comment: As for flags, have some [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator use `char *` datatype because in most systems the char size is 1 (1 byte) so is the ideal type to identify generic bytes in memory. As said by others `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` (form stdint.h) would be preferable for this usage.

You can think about flags as a set of booleans that get set, unset automatically. The most simple one is the Overflow flag that is set if the result of the previous operation add an overflow.

Comment: *Ultimately flags are used to detect errors in the code.* - absolutely not. Carry flag for example can be used to perform addition of data types larger than the natural word size. Zero or negative flag are useful for comparing data.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you are right i explain myself in a relay bad way i will adjust the response

Comment: According to the C Standard, a `char` is ***always*** exactly one byte in size.